# Please help to find a function representation for a power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I need help finding a function that can represent the series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{27(3x-1)^{n-1}}{(-9)^{n+1}}$$

Please help any way you can because I'm super confused

Comment: Use geometric series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20geometric%20series,previous%20term%20by%201%2F2.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

This is $$27 \cdot \frac{1}{(-9)(3x-1)} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{3x-1}{-9} \right)^n $$ Use $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n = \frac{1}{1-r} $$ (only valid for $|r|\lt 1$).

Comment: Using the formula for $\sum-{n\ge 0}(-1)^nr^n$ would be  a bit faster.

Comment: @Bernard Do you mean $\sum (-1)^n r^n$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the mistyping.

Comment: @Bernard Well, they would really take the same amount of time.

Comment: More or less. A bit less with the latter, and, in my opinion, ever well-bred young people should know both.

Comment: @Bernard It essentially depends on how quickly one’s brain can notice that $-(-x)=x$. Perhaps more importantly, ever well-bred young people should be able to derive one from the other.

Comment: This goes without saying.

Comment: @Bernard Saying it out loud doesn’t hurt ‍♂️

Comment: REALLY LOUD? ;o)

Comment: @Bernard Huh? I didn’t get that.

Comment: I was just joking…

Comment: @Bernard :D ${}{}$